# Why angularjs ignore ng-if?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-show, angularjs-ng-if

i try use  ng-if, but angular no compile him. Look in test code:

```
<ul class="tmmenu-admin-tabs-builder-panel-answer">
                        <li class="tmmenu-admin-tabs-builder-panel-portlet" ng-repeat="answer in answers">
                            <div>
                                <span ng-repeat="question in questions">
                                    <label ng-repeat="answer in question.answers">
                                        <input type="checkbox">{{question.id}}.{{answer.id+1}}
                                        <span ng-if="test()">ddd</span>
                                    </label>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <textarea>{{answer.text}}</textarea>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

and function test:

```
$scope.test = function(){
        console.log('d');
        return false;
    }
```

if run this page, we can see "ddd" in "Li" despite to test return false.

Next step, i replaced at "ng-if" "ng-show" :

```
<ul class="tmmenu-admin-tabs-builder-panel-answer">
    ...
    <span ng-show="test()">ddd</span>
    ...
</ul>
```

And its working, "ddd" hide. Why ng-if not working where working ng-show?

Comment: works fine in a simple non repeating situation. Create a demo in plnkr.co or jsfiddle.net that replicates problem

Answer (score 1):

**The ngIf directive removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree** based on an {expression}. If the expression assigned to ngIf evaluates to a false value then the element is removed from the DOM, otherwise a clone of the element is reinserted into the DOM.

---

**The ngShow directive shows or hides the given HTML** element based on the expression provided to the ngShow attribute. The element is shown or hidden by removing or adding the ng-hide CSS class onto the element. The .ng-hide CSS class is predefined in AngularJS and sets the display style to none (using an !important flag). For CSP mode please add angular-csp.css to your html file (see ngCsp).

Comment: Ok, but why ng-if not remove my <span ng-show="test()">ddd</span> block? Test() all time return false.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a scope problem, is there something in a child scope that might override the value for `test`?  ng-if works fine for me ([plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sMV8uRWNG5i5VamNdy2U?p=preview)).  I assume that everything else is working fine, are you seeing '`d`' in the console to show that your function is getting executed?

Try changing your tag to this to help debug and you should see that it is a function:

```
<span ng-if="test()">test is: {{test.toString()}}</span>
```